# Sylius - Inject Services into Resource Repositories

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, sylius

I want to add a feature to `AdminUser` so that an admin can only see products / orders etc. that are available in specific channels. The aim is to have an admin interface and use sylius as a multishop platform for different clients with different shops.

What I did so far:

- I created a custom resource repository for products that overrides the `createListQueryBuilder` method (and registered it in `_sylius.yaml` of course).
- Since I need symfonys security service and autowiring seems not to work for additional parameters in the repository constructor, I created a `CompilerPass` that adds a method call to set the security service (code below).

**Problem:**

The service gets set in the repository, but when the `createListQueryBuilder` method gets called it is `null` again - so there is not way to filter user specific.

It seems that during the call another instance of the repository class is used (spl_object_hash returns different values when `setSecurity` is called than when `createListQueryBuilder` is called).

Am I something missing or is there any other more sylius-way to add this feature?

Sylius Version 1.8.0

Code:

**ProductRepositoryCompilerPass**

```
namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

/**
 * Class ProductRepositoryCompilerPass
 *
 * This class injects the security service into the product repository for filtering.
 * @package App\DependencyInjection
 */
class ProductRepositoryCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if($container->hasDefinition('sylius.repository.product')) {
            $definition = $container->getDefinition('sylius.repository.product');
            $definition->addMethodCall('setSecurity', [new Reference(Security::class)]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Custom ProductRepository**

```
namespace App\Repository\Product;


use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class ProductRepository extends \Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\ORM\ProductRepository
{
    private $security;
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
    {
        parent::__construct($entityManager, $class);
    }

    public function setSecurity(Security $security) {
       $this->security = $security; // this gets called properly
    }

    public function createListQueryBuilder(string $locale, $taxonId = null): QueryBuilder
    {
        // $this->security is null here

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you follow this guide: https://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/customization/repository.html?

Answer (score -2):

---

Or you could remove dependency on security at repository level and create a security layer above repository.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please consider leaving a comment instead.